# Pass data to $scope in AngularJS chart

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using asp .net mvc web app with AngularJS and chart.js to create chart.

Taking the bar chart example:
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I have a list of data from MVC controller, and I would like to pass this  data to angular controller.
`/Displaycharts/Columnchart` is link to get datalist from c# controller to angular controller.

May I know the `$scope.labels` and `$scope.data` are assigned correctly?
Appreciate if you could help to modify the sample and SQL script which can be [downloaded from here](http://www.filedropper.com/mvcwithangularjs_1).

Thanks!

Code:

```
angular
    .module('MyApp', 'Chart.js', 'DisplaychartsngController.js')
    .controller('DisplaychartsngController', function ($scope, MarketService) {
        $scope.Markets = null;
        MarketService.GetMarketList().then(function (d) {
            $scope.Markets = d.data; //Success callback
            $scope.labels = $scope.Markets.PlanName;
            $scope.series= ['PaymentAmount'];
            $scope.data = $scope.Markets.PaymentAmount;

        }, function (error) {
            alert('Error!'); // Failed Callback
        });
    })
```

Comment: How does your response look like? And what do you wish to pass to `$scope.labels` and `$scope.data`?

Comment: I want to pass Markets.PlanName and Markets.PlanAmount to $scope.data.

and i think $scope.labels = ['PlanName', 'PaymentAmount'];

I tried $scope.data = [d.PlanName, d.PaymentAmount]; 
but it's failed.

Comment: `PlanName` seems to be a sting and `PaymentAmount` a number, right? `$scope.data` takes a series of data such as `[1,2,3,4]`. In case of a bar chart you assign either a single array or a set of arrays.

Comment: I have added the web application that I have developed. Appreciate if you can help to troubleshoot.

Comment: PlanName seems to be a string and PaymentAmount a number.
I tried with code below but it is still failed.
$scope.labels = ['PlanName', 'PaymentAmount'];
            $scope.data = [$scope.Markets.PlanName, $scope.Markets.PaymentAmount];

Answer (score 1):

If the data is returned as JSON to the $scope.Markets. Then you would apply it like an accessing of an object. For example:

```
$scope.Markets = d.data; //Success callback
$scope.labels = $scope.Markets.labels;  
$scope.data = $scope.Markets.data;
```

As I'm not sure on the format of the response I can't be certain, maybe comment with an example of the response if this isn't correct and I'll edit the answer.

EDIT:

HTML like this:

```
<div ng-controller="DisplaychartsngController">
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>
</div>
```

And a controller with this:

```
 angular.module("MyApp", ["chart.js"])
        .controller("DisplaychartsngController", function ($scope) {
             $scope.labels = ['Half Yearly', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly']
             $scope.data = [['17974', '152324','5393']]; 
             $scope.series = ['PaymentAmount']; //what you want to call your series
         });
```

Comment: I have added the web application that I have developed. Appreciate if you can help to troubleshoot.

Comment: A sample of the response would be more helpful.

Comment: I would like the list of data pass to chart X and Y axis data, and transform to a bar chart.

Comment: I get that. You want  ['PlanName', 'PaymentAmount'] as labels on the x axis and you need to get the data for the y axis. But as I don't know the format of the response from MarketService.GetMarketList() I can't give a proper answer yet.

Comment: I see. MarketService.GetMarketList() will get listdata from Displaycharts controller - ColumnCharts function.
The data is [PlanName, PaymentAmount]
17974 Half Yearly
152324 Quaretly
5393 Yearly

Comment: And you want to display this data in a bar chart? This would make more sense as a basic table.

Comment: I have successfully build a data table but my requirement is to display data in chart. There is no error in developer tool when executing, so I am not sure how to pass the data...

Comment: Okay let's give this a shot.
For a chart.js bar chart you pass the labels as the x axis. 
$scope.labels = ['Half Yearly', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly']
For the data it will be
$scope.data = [17974, 152324, 5393]

Can you extract this data from your d response?

Comment: I have tried but it is not working.

angular.
    module("MyApp", ["Chart.js"])
    .controller("DisplaychartsngController", function ($scope)
    {                
        $scope.labels = ['Half Yearly', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly'];                
        $scope.data = ['17974', '152324','5393'];      
    }, 
    function (error) 
    {
        alert('Error!'); // Failed Callback
    }
)

Comment: Made an edit fixing some of your code. You gave a controller so I used that.

Comment: And you have html like in my example?

Comment: Sorry for long discussion here, could you please attach your example?
I tried to copy to my script but it is not working.

Comment: The example is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are assigning data in appropriate format **(array)**, Like:

```
$scope.labels = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
```

Hope this helps.